# Extra spaces on labels including cyrillic symbols in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, encoding

I'm trying to make a simple plot in R using ggplot2. The data is stored in a dataframe with its column written in Russian. The problem is that the contents of the label is shifted from the right border of the latter. These extra spaces appeared whether the label names are defined explicitly (the code below) or implicitly from the dataframe column names.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = drat, y =mpg, color = cyl))+
  geom_point() +
  labs(color = "Русское название") +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", linetype = "solid", size = 0.7),
        legend.justification = c(1, 1),
        legend.position = c(1, 1),
        legend.title.align = 0)
```

[image: The picture with Russian title]

The plot with the English title is depicted appropriately.

[image: The picture with english title]

The encoding of the operational system is set as follows:

> "LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251"

Is there a way to cope this problem?

Comment: A figure would help clarify the problem, but have you tried adding something like `legend.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, unit = "pt")` to the `theme()`?

Comment: The plots have been added. I've tried this option as well as the other ones which are responsible for spacing. The picture remained the same.

Comment: what version of ggplot & R are you using. I see a legend like the English version

Comment: R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) and ggplot2_3.1.0

Comment: I can replicate this problem when I plot to RStudio's graphics device, but not if I save the plot directly using `ggsave`. I've tested with .png / .jpg / .svg, & they all worked fine. (.pdf didn't, though that might be because I don't have cyrillic fonts...)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when needed legend with cyrillic symbols. Looks like it is known issue [reported](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4123) in ggplot2 repo because of the default graphic device on Windows. Actually, if you would try to save your ggplot with ggsave, probably you won't get that issue.

I have not tried to save files by myself yet, but I have followed the reported issue and found some workaround specific for R studio [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2142) and it has worked for me, maybe it can solve your issue too. Sample code to run before plotting anything is:

```r
trace(grDevices:::png, quote({
  if (missing(type) && missing(antialias)) {
    type <- "cairo-png"
    antialias <- "subpixel"
  }
}), print = FALSE)
```